# I had complained or complained

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

I complained to someone and they did not reply back. So I want to write a mail again to them. I am confused which is correct:

> I **had complained** to you but you have not replied yet.

Or

> I **complained** to you but you have not replied yet.

Please also tell if its first one that is past perfect tense then why past perfect?
For me first one sounds correct.

Comment: No, the second one is correct, the first one isn't. There are numerous questions about use of the past perfect, both here and on the English Language Learners site.

Comment: You actually used "I complained" in setting out your question. Your email is exactly the same.

Comment: Had you done it prior to this time or did you do it at this time?

Comment: @HotLicks I did not get your question

Comment: Which of the two options are you trying to describe?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Past simple is used to talk about an action that happened in the past, without any further reference. Past perfect is used to talk about an action that happened before another action in the past (which is usually expressed by the past simple).

An example including both: *On Monday I **complained** to you, I **had** already **complained** on Friday, but you have not replied yet.*

About the sentences you proposed the correct one is the second.

> I **complained** to you but you have not replied yet.

Some references:
https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/simpas-pasper https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/past-simple-or-past-perfect

Comment: Hello, Luke. As you might imagine, this is hardly the first time this has been said on ELU.

Comment: Luke thank you for answering and +1 for references. I read your references, sorry this may be a silly question but just wanted to ask you what if we use **already** in the sentence then can we use had? 'I **had already complained** to you but you have not replied yet.'

Comment: You can use any indication to an action that happened before another action in the past.

Comment: Give reasons for downvote please.